# Can we integrate sonar without maven?

Tags: maven, integration, sonarqube

My question is can we run sonar on .net projects without using maven?
I want to avoid the complexity of maven

Any Help ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before asking trivial questions on stackoverflow, please read the documentation: it is very clear about that => "To run a Sonar analysis on a C# solution, it is recommended to use the Sonar Runner."

- Doc: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Ecosystem
- Example: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/csharp

Comment: actually my problem is still there because I want to build my project with hudson+msbuild its work fine after that in the post build action I want to trigger SONAR to run its Analysis here it requires Maven_Opts & Maven POM file

Comment: You can add a "Standalone Sonar Analysis" build step, no need for Maven. Please read the documentation: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+Sonar+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonaronJenkinsJob-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswiththeSonarRunner

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a build tool like Ant, Maven, or Gradle, you can use the standalone [Sonar Runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Runner).